# Count in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an object like this in javascript, how can I count the number of elements in [A, B, C, D, etc.]?

```
{ "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D", ... ] }
```

And if i have:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "value" : { "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D" ] } }
{ "_id" : "2", "value" : { "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" ] } }
```

How can I convert it to the following structure?

```
{ "_id" : "1", "value" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "2", "value" : 6 }
```

Thanks

Comment: `obj.test.length`. have a look at some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: you can actually check it in the chrome console like so:
`o = { "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D"] }`, 
`o.test.length = 4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var data = [{ "_id" : "1", "value" : { "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D" ] } },{ "_id" : "2", "value" : { "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F" ] } }];

var arr = data.map((d) => {
    d["value"] = d["value"].test.length;
    return d;
});
console.log(arr);
```

**EDIT**

The more smart way is to simply use a forEach loop in the following way

```js
var data = [{ "_id" : "1", "value" : { "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D" ] } },{ "_id" : "2", "value" : { "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F" ] } }];

data.forEach((d) => {
    d["value"] = d["value"].test.length;
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Why use map to create a new array with the same objects which are then modified? If the objects can be modified a `forEach` would suffice, if not a `data.map((d) => Object.assign(d, { value: d.value.test.length })` would match (my?) expectations of a map not having side-effects.

Comment: I agree to you and i have added a forEach version

Answer (score 1):

If can always do `.length` on an object check the example below:

```js
var obj = { "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"] };
console.log(obj.test.length)
```

EDIT:

For your second question

you can do

`obj.value = obj.value.test.length;`

```js
var obj = { "_id" : "2", "value" : { "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" ] } };
obj.value = obj.value.test.length;
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the answer changed from generic javascript to mongodb, I have to update the answer to reflect the question:

Instead of using map/reduce in mongo, consider using the aggregation framework mongodb provides, it allows for very powerful querying.
In this case, [you want the `$size` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([
  { $project: { value: { $size: "$value.test" } } }
])
```

Unless explicitly removed, mongodb will always include the document `_id` so for this use case we only need to address the `value`, if you need any other value from the documents in your result-set, add them like:

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([
  { $project: { 
    value: { $size: "$value.test" },
    foo: '$foo',
    bar: '$bar',
    baz: '$baz',
  } }
])
```

---

**Original answer (pure js, no mongodb)**

I suspect the example is actually part of an array

```
{ "_id" : "1", "value" : { "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D" ] } }
{ "_id" : "2", "value" : { "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ] } }
```

So I assume you want to map a large set of records this way, and you don't want to (accidentally) destroy the original value property (as other answers do), here's how I'd do this:

```
const list = [
  { "_id" : "1", "value" : { "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D" ] } },
  { "_id" : "2", "value" : { "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ] } }
];
//  map the list into a new list of object containing the _id and value count
const mapped = list.map((record) => {
    return {
          _id: record._id,
          //  assuming there's only test and it's an array 
          value: record.value.test.length,
    };
});
```

If `value` inside each record is an object which may contain zero or more  arrays and you wish to count the total amount of items inside all of them, you can `reduce` the arrays into a total number.

```js
const list = [
  { "_id" : "1", "value" : { "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D" ] } },
  { "_id" : "2", "value" : { "test" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ] } },
  { "_id" : "3", "value" : { } },
  { "_id" : "4", "value" : { "test" : [ "A", "B" ], "test2" : [ "C", "D", "E" ] } },
];
//  map the list into a new list of object containing the _id and value count
const mapped = list.map((record) => {
  return {
    _id: record._id,
    //  assuming there's zero or more arrays
    value: Object.keys(record.value)
      //  filter out any non-array
      .filter((key) => Array.isArray(record.value[key]))
      //  reduce the arrays into their combined length
      .reduce((carry, key) => carry + record.value[key].length, 0),
  };
});
  
console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your array with a simple `forEach` loop - like below:

```js
var data = [{
    "_id": "1",
    "value": {
      "test": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "value": {
      "test": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    }
  }
];

var dataCount = [];

data.forEach(function(element) {
  var newElement = {};
  newElement._id = element._id;
  newElement.value = element.value.test.length;

  dataCount.push(newElement);
  //console.log(newElement);
});

console.log(dataCount);
```

Comment: Excuse me, I'm doing this with a mongodb mapreduce so it does not work. I get {"_id": "1", "value": {"test": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]}} and I can not modify the object [object object]

Comment: @Carla ok, but the information in your question does not indicate this is a mongodb/mapreduce issue. only JS/array...